# Text of final blessing following haftarah of Yom Kippur

Tags: tefilla, blessing, yom-kippur, haftarah

In my (*nusach ashkenaz*) *machzor* for Yom Kippur, the final blessing after the *haftarah* of *shacharit* concludes:

> ודברך אמת וקיים לעד. ברוך אתה ה' מלך מוחל וסולח לעוונותינו וכו'‏
>
> And Your word is true and enduring forever. Blessed are you Hashem, King Who forgives and pardons our iniquities etc.

What is this phrase ודברך אמת וקיים לעד doing here?

It appears many times on Rosh HaShanah (at the conclusion of the fourth blessing of each *amidah*, at the conclusion of the nighttime *kiddush* blessing, and at the conclusion of the final *haftarah* blessing), but this is the only time it appears on Yom Kippur.

If it is as appropriate for Yom Kippur as it is for Rosh HaShanah, then why not include it in the Yom Kippur *amidah*? Conversely, if it is not appropriate for the Yom Kippur *amidah*, then why is it appropriate for the blessings after the Yom Kippur *haftarah*?

Comment: The question is backwards (though I don't blame you for not realizing it). That phrase is a Yom Kippur Amida phrase that got borrowed to Rosh Hashana davening, and then later dropped from Yom Kippur davening when other lines were added there (in particular the קדשנו... piece from regular Yom Tov). There are lots of variations among communities which pieces of regular Yom Tov Amida get put in for RH/YK (Yaaleh veYavo, veHassieinu, Kadesheinu, Melokh even on YK) and then that affects how you'd tie off the blessing at the end